# ExtJS 4.2.0 undefined model

Tags: javascript, extjs, store

I *thought* I had defined a model for my store, but my console and also my application seem to  disagree.

My code looks something like this:

```
Ext.define("Deeper", {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [{
                name: 'ID',
                type: 'int'
            }, {
                name: 'someoneElsesID',
                type: 'int'
            }, {
                name: 'anotherID',
                type: 'int'
            }],
            belongsTo: 'Higher'
        });

Ext.define("Higher", {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [{
                name: 'name',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'status',
                type: 'int'
            }],
            hasMany: {
                model: 'Deeper',
                name: 'deeper'
            }

        });
```

after that, I created the following store:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'Higher',
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'some/correct/url.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'name'
                }
            }
        });
```

My grid shows inline data correctly, so I tried `console.debug(store)`

The result is: 
`model: undefined`
and
`modelDefaults: null`

So where did I go wrong?

Comment: Have you required you model class somehow (in your application class or otherwise)? Also, you should put the proxy in the model to save you from having to declare it for each store.

Comment: At first I had not required it, but I changed that after receiving an error - not getting the error anymore, but it's still not working. The proxy is just used once, so it doesn't matter that much, but thanks for that hint.

Comment: That's probably still a dependency/require issue. Your code is correct, and if you paste it all in one single file, you could confirm it's working. Try wrapping your store code with `Ext.require('Higher', function() { /* put your code here */ });`.

Comment: I did, but it still doesn't work... I deleted the `hasMany`-part in my `Higher`-section and now my model is defined. But I thought this would be the way to include my `Deeper`-part. How else could I solve this?

Comment: That's weird, I thought model associations were resolved when the associated model class becomes available... And that they never blocked the model definition itself. Anyway, you should try to add `requires: ['Deeper']` in `Higher`'s definition.